# How to check if Windows prompts a notification box using python?

Tags: python, windows

How do I check if windows prompts a notification box asking for some admin permissions like this using python?
[image]

Before asking this question I've tried using `PIL.imagegrab`for capturng screenshots and then training the program to distinguish between those images which have a permission seeking boxes and those who don't.
Is there any simpler possible way to get to know about this?

Comment: Enumerate child windows of fogeground window and check if any of them have class name of UAC prompt. In windows 7 it's "DirectUIHWND".